# How to Remove Inverted Commas from a Power BI Power Query Column?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-cleaning

I am trying to remove inverted commas from a column in Power BI Power Query using the code `dataset['Column1'] = dataset['Custom'].apply(remove_quotes)`, where remove_quotes is defined as `def remove_quotes(s): return s.replace('"', '').replace("'", '')`. However, I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'`. How can I modify my code to remove the inverted commas from the column without getting this error?